# Is there an all(map(...)) optimization in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, dictionary

I'd like to use `all(map(func, iterables))`, because it is clear, but I'm very interested in whether this approach is optimized? For example, if any calculated result of `map()` is not `True` mapping should stop.

Example from my project:

```
for item in candidate_menu:
    if not item.is_max_meals_amount_ok(daily_menus):
        return False
return True
```

I prefer to use functional-like style:

```
all(map(operator.methodcaller('is_max_meals_amount_ok', daily_menus), candidate_menu)
```

I there any optimization for `all(map(...))` or `any(map(...))` in Python?

Edit: Python 2.7 on board.

Comment: Both `any` and `all` are lazy in the standard library

Comment: `map()` is lazy on Python 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to `all(func(i) for i in iterable)` suggested by others, you can also use `itertools.imap` - `all(imap(func, iterable))`. Compared to `map`, `imap` is an iterator thus if `all` stops consuming from it, it won't advance any further.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: this answer isn't True for Python 3, where map is a generator!

No. `all` and `any` are short-circuited, but `map` isn't: it can't know that it was called from a bit of code that does short circuiting, and always just returns the full list.

The solution is to use generator expressions:

```
all(func(i) for i in iterables)
```

That does short-circuit.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get lazy evaluation in Python 2.x, try:

```
all(func(i) for i in iterables)
```

This will not build the whole list then evaluate, unlike `map`. In Python 3.x, `map` returns an iterator so will be lazy by default.

Answer (score 1):

"all/any" do use short circuits.

but it wouldn't propagate across the map() command ,

to  do that , change map to a generator

```
all(func(x) for x in iterable)
```

should work